# Sockets stuck in Sent/Recv state

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I recently stumbled across very strange bug. I first thought it was bug in my code, but right now I can see this is something system-wide, having said that, I think my problem fits SO best.

I was seeing very strange behavior of my network library and when I started debugging I discovered that if I will connect to a tcp socket, most often - soon after I started listening my sockets will get "stuck" in SYN_RCVD and SYN_SENT state. After even more debugging I dropped all my code altogether and I was left with this:

```
while (true)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(54000);
    listener.Start();
    var c = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 54000));

    c.Result.Close();
    client.Close();
    listener.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

(classes above are `System.Net.Sockets1`s, not mine).

This code, on my machine will produce 1-5 `done`s and then will hang with 3 sockets: listening socket (bound to `0.0.0.0:54000` in listening state and 2 sockets, one stuck in SYN_RCVD, other one in SYN_SENT). I tried that on different machine, code runs ok, then I tried that on Linux VM on my 'broken' machine and it still does run ok.

Similar code in Node.js gets stuck as well.

Comment: Possibly a bad firewall configuration?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart On localhost? And I think it would be more binary, works or not, here I have pretty random "crashes". I started removing all network drivers like Check Point vpn, updated drivers, rebooted computer and strangely enough, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I start to think it may correlate with vpn.

Comment: The code above doesn't really seem sensible. There's no guarantee the previous connection will be completely torn down when you try to create the new listener. Closing and re-opening the same port repeatedly just isn't sane.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I thought about it, but: in original code I was experimenting with more sensible closing, this one was created as a totally simplistic example, but: if the problem would be with not closed listening socket shouldn't I receive an error while creating new one (port is already used..), instead - I create listener successfully, it's Connect that crashes. Point 2 - this bug happens sometimes at first loop, so resource management isn't an issue, because they `Connect` can hang before I will ever get to closing sockets for the first time.

Comment: @MarcinDeptuła What do you mean by "crashes"? How can a connect crash?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz by crashes I mean it stucks in the scenario I described above (2 sockets, one in syn_rcvd one in sync_sent state for few seconds, after which connection is timed out). So listener is working, socket for newly created connection is created, but they never finish handshake. For asynchronous method this means that callback for ConnectAsync is never called. 
Right now I think I'm in the state it works, but I'm still trying to pinpoint what was the cause and if it will come back. I'm leaning towards Microsoft's driver for Intel network card right now.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz FYI, if you care, I think I pinpointed it to CheckPoint VPN. It installs some Windows service, when I turned it off (I often do) this code crashes after 1-10 loops, when it's on, about after 3-30k iterations, when I completely remove it, I can run it for over 500k iterations without a problem. I will play with it and if I can confirm I guess I will delete the question. Strangest bug I ever had.